# How to build and use a graph-algo in neo4j 2.0?

Tags: neo4j, a-star

I want to use aStar algorithm via REST? I've downloaded the Neo4j server. How to add a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

aStar doesn't seem to be included in the REST API. You could [write a plugin](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html) that does that for you. It's relatively easy to implement with the [java API](http://api.neo4j.org/2.1.0-M01/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html#aStar%28org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpander,%20org.neo4j.graphalgo.CostEvaluator,%20org.neo4j.graphalgo.EstimateEvaluator%29).

Comment: and why the algorithm is not included in REST? it work?